# Declaring array of objects without specified size as class field

Tags: c++, arrays

The field has to be immutable so I can't use the vector. Is there a way to do it like in the title?

I want to do something like this:

```
typedef list<pair<int,string>> list_pair;
class tree{
  private:
     list_pair arr[]{
  public:
    tree(int size){
      arr[size];
    }
}
```

Comment: *The field has to be immutable so I can't use the vector* What about `const std::vector<int>`?

Comment: You could template it: `tree<5>`.

Comment: Remember (or learn) the differences between *initialization* and *assignment*. You can *initialize* a constant (immutable) variable, but assign to it.

Comment: If you can't use vector or `std::unique_ptr<list_pair[]>` you will have to use `new`. If you do  so remember your class should follow the rule of 3 or 5.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do it like in the title?

No.

A non-static member array must have a known size, there is no way around that in C++.

> The field has to be immutable so I can't use the vector.

Your example array of non-const isn't immutable either.

Furthermore, I don't see a reason why that should matter. It's a private member, so it's fairly easy to choose to not mutate it. That way the class remains effectively immutable from the outside. Conclusion: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is that normal to adding list_pairs with for loop in the constructor? I need something like this: Vector{List{pair, pair...} , List{}, List{}...}

Comment: @nadirhan Loops are normal in constructors.